# JavaScript working in Firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript

No errors in web console, the code is used to hide one element and show another.
The **stats** and **measure** ID's appear only once in the html..
The **a** and **b** ID's also appears one time only.
It works fine in Mozilla Firefox but not in chrome.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>HeartBeat</title>
<style>
body {
    background: #eee;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
.conta{
    max-width: 750px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
.head {

    background: #FF6969;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;

}
.bd {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FD0000;
}
#stats {
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
    color: #423C3C;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FD0000;

}
h1 {
    color:#667184;
}
h2 {
    color:#D0D4DB;
}
.two-col {
display:block;
max-width: 50%;
min-width: 49%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
.three-col {
display:inline-block;
max-width: 33%;
min-width: 32%;
float: center;
text-align: center;
}
.text-center {
text-align: center;
}
.row {
max-width:100%;
}
.white-back {
background: #fff;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="conta">
    <div class="head">
        <img src="h-1.png" width="50px" style="float:left; margin: -10px;"> Heart<b>Beat</b>
    </div>
    <div class="bd">

            <div class="two-col"><a id="a" class="active" onClick='aTab()' href="#">Measure</a></div>
            <div class="two-col"><a id="b" onClick='bTab()' href="#">Statistics</a></div>
         <br/> <br/>

        <div id="measure" class="text-center">
            <img src="heart.jpg" width="90%">
            <h1><span class="light">0</span>72</h1>
            <h2>Beats Per Second</h2>
            <img src="wave.png" alt="" width="90%" >
        </div>
        <div id="stats" class="text-center"> <br/>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="three-col"><a href="#">Day</a></div>
            <div class="three-col"><a href="#">Month</a></div>
            <div class="three-col"><a href="#">Year</a></div>
            </div><div class="row"><br/> <br/>
            <img src="cntr_img.jpg" alt="" width="80%"><br/>
            <div class="three-col"><h2>Max</h2><h2>50</h2></div>
            <div class="three-col"><h2>Min</h2><h2>157</h2></div>
            <div class="three-col"><h2>Avg</h2><h2>81</h2></div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function aTab() {
        document.getElementById("stats").style="display: none;";
        document.getElementById("measure").style="display: block;";
        document.getElementById("b").className="";
        document.getElementById("a").className="active";
    }
    function bTab() {
        document.getElementById("stats").style="display: block;";
        document.getElementById("measure").style="display: none;";
        document.getElementById("b").className="active";
        document.getElementById("a").className="";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I. Have edited the code .

Comment: Can you also post the html part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `style = "somestring"`, instead use `style.someProperty = someValue`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/JosephGarrone/5yjnosh3/) is a fiddle showing working code in chrome.

Here is the code (Only JS was changed):

```
function aTab() {
  document.getElementById("stats").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("measure").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("b").className="";
  document.getElementById("a").className="active";
}
function bTab() {
  document.getElementById("stats").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("measure").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("b").className="active";
  document.getElementById("a").className="";
}
```

However, I would probably rewrite your current JavaScript a little to make it a little bit more efficient. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/JosephGarrone/5yjnosh3/4/) is how I would normally have written something like that. Code here:

```
function GID(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var statsTab = GID("stats");
var measureTab = GID("measure");
var a = GID("a");
var b = GID("b");

function aTab() {
  statsTab.style.display = "none";
  measureTab.style.display = "block";
  a.className = "active";
  b.className = "";
}

function bTab() {
  statsTab.style.display = "block";
  measureTab.style.display = "none";
  a.className = "";
  b.className = "active";
}
```

Comment: @ShivamTiwari, a side note, it may be easier from a maintenance point of view to instead add/remove classes from `statsTab` and `measureTab` instead of setting css properties in the JavaScript. Also might pay to give `a` and `b` slightly more descriptive names. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this... use `style.propertyName` and it will work in all browser and read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) . Always try to use standard method as some browser may or may not support some feature.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>HeartBeat</title>
<style>
body {
    background: #eee;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
.conta{
    max-width: 750px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
.head {

    background: #FF6969;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;

}
.bd {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FD0000;
}
#stats {
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
    color: #423C3C;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FD0000;

}
h1 {
    color:#667184;
}
h2 {
    color:#D0D4DB;
}
.two-col {
display:block;
max-width: 50%;
min-width: 49%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
.three-col {
display:inline-block;
max-width: 33%;
min-width: 32%;
float: center;
text-align: center;
}
.text-center {
text-align: center;
}
.row {
max-width:100%;
}
.white-back {
background: #fff;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="conta">
    <div class="head">
        <img src="h-1.png" width="50px" style="float:left; margin: -10px;"> Heart<b>Beat</b>
    </div>
    <div class="bd">

            <div class="two-col"><a id="a" class="active" onClick='aTab()' href="#">Measure</a></div>
            <div class="two-col"><a id="b" onClick='bTab()' href="#">Statistics</a></div>
         <br/> <br/>

        <div id="measure" class="text-center">
            <img src="heart.jpg" width="90%">
            <h1><span class="light">0</span>72</h1>
            <h2>Beats Per Second</h2>
            <img src="wave.png" alt="" width="90%" >
        </div>
        <div id="stats" class="text-center"> <br/>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="three-col"><a href="#">Day</a></div>
            <div class="three-col"><a href="#">Month</a></div>
            <div class="three-col"><a href="#">Year</a></div>
            </div><div class="row"><br/> <br/>
            <img src="cntr_img.jpg" alt="" width="80%"><br/>
            <div class="three-col"><h2>Max</h2><h2>50</h2></div>
            <div class="three-col"><h2>Min</h2><h2>157</h2></div>
            <div class="three-col"><h2>Avg</h2><h2>81</h2></div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function aTab() {
        document.getElementById("stats").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("measure").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("b").className="";
        document.getElementById("a").className="active";
    }
    function bTab() {
        document.getElementById("stats").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("measure").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("b").className="active";
        document.getElementById("a").className="";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```